# how to filter list on keydown event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how to filter list on keydown event in jquery ?I want to make `autocomplete` to filter my list by `input` field 
**here is my code**

https://jsbin.com/wamaficase/edit?html,js,output

```
 $(function () {
        $('#user').keyup(function (e) {
            var $item =$('#item li');
            var val =this.value;
            var $newItem =$item.filter(function (i,item) {
                console.log($(item).text())
                return $(item).text().indexOf(val)!= -1;
            })
            console.log($newItem)
        });

    });
```

I am getting the updated list in `newItem` variable how to show in view ?

**Expected out**

when user type `h` it show `hello ,bhnm,chuy` item in list

Comment: Have you looked at the console output while you're running it?

Comment: yes it sow `three ` `li` but how to show this

Comment: Do you mean filter it and update it using **keydown** event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used jQuery to toggle a hidden class on those list items to only render those that have the typed text.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#user').keyup(function(e) {
    var $items = $('#item li');

    var val = this.value;

    var $newItems = $items.each(function(i, item) {

      if (!val || $(item).text().indexOf(val) === -1) {
        $(item).addClass('hidden');
      } else {
        $(item).removeClass('hidden');
      }
    })

  });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="user" />
  </div>
  <ul id="item">
    <li class='hidden'>hello</li>
    <li class='hidden'>pwny</li>
    <li class='hidden'>chuy</li>
    <li class='hidden'>myuio</li>
    <li class='hidden'>bhnm</li>
    <li class='hidden'>ssd</li>
    <li class='hidden'>iopo</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why `filter is not used`